# equilateral hexagon with rounded corners with border and text inside, I can’t reflect the border Why?

Tags: html, css, svg

Have equilateral hexagon with rounded corners and border css text inside.

Everything is fine, I can’t understand why I can’t reflect the border on the upper left side:

[image: screenshot]

```html
<div class="universe__item">

  <div class='hex border'>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="292" height="292" preserveAspectRatio='none'>
          <path d="
              M138 7.04
                a14 14 0 0 1 14 0
                l108.97560733739 62.91
                a14 14 0 0 1 7 12.12
                l0 125.83419246269
                a14 14 0 0 1 -7 12.12
                l-108.97560733739 62.91
                a14 14 0 0 1 -14 0
                l-108.97560733739 -62.91
                a14 14 0 0 1 -7 -12.12
                l 2.004110622581e-13 -125.83
                a14 14 0 0 1 7 -12.12" vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'>
            </path>
        </svg>

    <span>Some<br>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.  PS: I already edited your question to contain the Code snippet and included the picture directly.

Answer (score 3):

You did not close the path with `z`. eg, `-12.12z`

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

svg {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="universe__item">

  <div class='hex border'>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="292" height="292" preserveAspectRatio='none'>
          <path d="
              M138 7.04
                a14 14 0 0 1 14 0
                l108.97560733739 62.91
                a14 14 0 0 1 7 12.12
                l0 125.83419246269
                a14 14 0 0 1 -7 12.12
                l-108.97560733739 62.91
                a14 14 0 0 1 -14 0
                l-108.97560733739 -62.91
                a14 14 0 0 1 -7 -12.12
                l 2.004110622581e-13 -125.83
                a14 14 0 0 1 7 -12.12z">
            </path>
        </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```